# unable to update object using hooks in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that will update my object value depending on the app name using useState hook. But I am not able to use the hook, it gives error invalid hook call.

Any other way to achieve the same will also work.

```
var myfun = (function() {

  const APP_NAME= "sample app"
  const [object, setObject] = useState({obj: 'value'})

  if(APP_NAME =="sample app") {
        setObject({obj:'new value'})
         console.log('here')
     }
      return object
});

myfun();
```

Comment: where is this function called (should be inside a component) ? + the 'return obj' will probably fail since obj is not defined.

Comment: Could you share the complete error that you're getting?

Comment: why are you using useState in function . if you are using  functional component, it always return jsx or null.

Comment: @JiaSH i have updated the code, i m trying to get updated object from the return statement.

Comment: Why would the application name change?

Comment: @Soorajs i m new to the react, i want to update the value of the object based on the app name I get. I am using same code for multiple app.

Comment: @Andy i am using same code for 3 apps. i am using the env file to change things inside the app based on the app name

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Hook instead of that Function:

```js
const useMyFun = () => {
    const [object, setObject] = useState({obj: 'value'});

    const APP_NAME = 'sample name';

    useEffect(() => {
        if (APP_NAME === 'sample name') setObject({obj: APP_NAME});
    }, [APP_NAME]);

    return object;
}


// In the component you need it:

const SomeComponent = () => {

    // will update if state changes in the useMyFun Hook;
    const appname = useMyFun();


    // rest of your component code
    ...
}
```

make sure you use functional components to use this.

NOTE: but this will only be useful if APP_NAME will ever change.
otherwhise you could just use a simple ternary operator:

```js
   const object = APP_NAME === 'sample name' ? {obj: APP_NAME} : {obj: 'value'}
```

Comment: I have to call the function in the same file and when I am calling it, I have the error invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Comment: Well the error is explicit: 'Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.' You can not use hooks outside a component lifecycle ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the hook call outside the function like this and the invalid hook call error will disapear i think :

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState({ obj: "value" });

  const myfun = () => {
    const APP_NAME = "sample app";
    if (APP_NAME === "sample app") {
      setObject({ obj: "new value" });
      console.log("here");
    }
    return object;
  };

  myfun();

  return (
    ....
  );
}

export default App;
```

i hope this helps you .

Answer (score -1):

If all the above answers don't work look for an infinite react hook loop (usually with useEffect);